# Showing that $\operatorname {Br}(\Bbb F_q)=0$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, group-cohomology

I want to prove that $\operatorname {Br}(\Bbb F_q)=0$ using the cohomological description of the Brauer group.

We have:

$\operatorname {Br}(\Bbb F_q)=H^2(\operatorname {Gal}(\overline {\Bbb F_q}/\Bbb F_q), \overline {\Bbb F_q}^*)$.

Since $\operatorname {Gal}(\overline {\Bbb F_q}/\Bbb F_q)$ is just $\widehat {\Bbb Z}$, this is just

$H^2(\widehat{\Bbb Z}, \overline {\Bbb F_q}^*) = \operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z[\widehat{\Bbb Z}]}^2(\Bbb Z, \overline {\Bbb F_q}^*)$.

So I just need to find a free $\Bbb Z[\widehat{\Bbb Z}]$-resolution of $\Bbb Z$:

$$...\to \Bbb Z[\widehat{\Bbb Z}] \to \Bbb Z\to 0$$

But already the kernel of the first map is complicated. Any suggestions?

EDIT: as suggested by @Mariano, I'll try another approach.

Assume $\operatorname {Br}(\Bbb F_q)\neq 0$ and let $D$ be division algebra over $\Bbb F_q$. Then $\dim_{\Bbb F_q} D = n^2$ for some integer $n$. Let $l=q^{n^2}$. Then it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Br}(\Bbb F_l / \Bbb F_q) =0$. $\operatorname {Gal}({\Bbb F_l}/\Bbb F_q)=\Bbb Z/n^2\Bbb Z$, so I need to compute $\operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/n^2\Bbb Z]}^2(\Bbb Z, \overline {\Bbb F_l^*})$

Comment: Regarding your edit: the coefficients you nred to consider are the multiplicative group, not the additive group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, oops a detail I forgot.

Answer (score 5):

That cohomology group of the Galois group is not normal cohomology but continuous cohomology with respect to the Krull topology on the Galois group. In particular, your approach does not have many chances.

Now, the definition of both Krull topology and of continuous cohomology are made so that you can reduce everything to computing cohomology of finite quotients of the Galois group, which are cyclic. You should consult a textbook on Galois cohomology.

Comment: Hi Mariano, thank you for your answers. I believed I figured out my other problem, but I'm still struggling with this one. I spent the whole day looking at different text books for Galois and group cohomology; I believe I'd need to take a whole week revisiting it, so that's why I'm posting some questions here to see where I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if your acquiescence to Mariano's suggestion of an alternate method means that you're open to different proofs, or if that is just another flavor of 'cohomological'. If so, then I apologize for not answering your actual question.

There is a much 'simpler' proof that finite fields have trivial Brauer group. If you are willing to move out of the cohomological point of view which, since we have the luxury of thinking about the Brauer group in several ways, seems like a good use of knowledge.

Now, finite fields are quasi-algebraically closed by an extremely famous theorem of [Chevalley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).

So, let $D$ be a division algebra over $\mathbb{F}_q$, of splitting degree $n$. We must show that $n=1$. But, if $e_1,\ldots,e_{n^2}$ is a $\mathbb{F}_q$-basis for $D$, then the reduced norm on $D$ can be interpreted as a homogenous polynomial in degree $n^2$.

More rigorously, there exists some homogenous $f(T_1,\ldots,T_{n^2})\in \mathbb{F}_q[T_1,\ldots,T_{n^2}]$ such that for any $\displaystyle x=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\alpha_i e_i\in D$, where $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{F}_q$, we have that the reduced norm of $x$ is $f(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n^2})$. But, since the reduced norm of a non-zero element of $D$ is non-zero, we know that $f(T_1,\ldots,T_{n^2})$ has no non-trivial zeros. The quasi-algebraically closedness of $\mathbb{F}_q$ then implies that $n\geqslant n^2$, and so $n=1$ as desired.

I hope that was sufficiently cute, as to turn you away from a direct $H^2$ calculation :)

Comment: Thanks Alex!, This looks indeed like a cute proof but I'll have to look into the theorems of Chevalley-Warning and "reduced norms" before I can actually say that I understand it. I actually need to prove the statement that $\operatorname{Br}(\Bbb F_q) =0$ using the cohomological description of the Brauer group though. So if you could give me any further help in setting up the calculation, I'd be really happy. I'm reading Serre Local fields now following Mariano's suggestions but it is quite a task to review all of the theory and then figure out how to proceed in one specific example.

Comment: @Rodrigo It just seems silly to try and do this cohomologically. It's unnatural. There is another proof which is less cute, but may be more known to you. The Brauer group of a finite field classifies central division algebras over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of finite dimension. These are all just $\mathbb{F}_q$ by Weddurburn's theorem on finite division algebras.

Comment: Using Chevalley's theorem isnquite thermonuclear ;-)