# Computing $H^\bullet(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, derived-functors

This is related to this other question of mine [Showing that $\operatorname {Br}(\Bbb F_q)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780209/showing-that-operatorname-br-bbb-f-q-0) in which I also got stuck at writing a free resolution. I want to compute the group cohomology $H^\bullet(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) = H^\bullet(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z)$ and, more specifically, show that it is non zero in infinitely many levels.

I have $H^\bullet(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) = \operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z]} (\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z)$. So I look for a free $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z]$-resolution of $\Bbb Z$. Let me write $C_n = \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for clarity and pick a generator $g\in C_n$.

$$...\to \oplus_{i=1}^n \Bbb Z[C_n] \xrightarrow{r_1} \Bbb Z[C_n] \xrightarrow{r_0} \Bbb Z \to 0$$

where $r_0$ sends $g\mapsto 1$ and $r_1$ sends the generator $g_i$ of the $i$-th summand to $g^i -1$. But I am stuck in trying to write the next term (and hopefully see a periodicity).

Comment: Every homological álgebra textbook which treats group cohomologymdoes in detail the computation of the cohomology of cyclic groups. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can I ask you something on chat? It's not urgent though.

Comment: Cooking now :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 4-term exact sequence
$$
0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[C_n]\xrightarrow{1-\sigma}\mathbb Z[C_n]\to\mathbb Z\to0
$$
giving rise to a 2-periodic free resolution of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma$?

Comment: @Rodrigo A generator of $C_n$.